# Why does MS Word open two tabs for a certain URL?

Tags: microsoft-word, url

When I put this URL in a MS Word document https://1url.cz/xM69U and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click, Chrome opens two tabs!

Not sure why this is happening. The original url which is shortened there is quite complicated (see below), but that shouldn't matter, right? Or does MS Word try to be clever (oh god no please...) and resolve the shortened URL himself and then fails there?

https://birds.cz/avif/obs.php?request_id=616588509&sf=1&dm=0&url_fmt_ver=0.2&iDisplayLength=100&pager_PaginationType=full_numbers&gal_width=3&iDisplayStart=0&iSortCol_0=0&iSortDir_0=desc&current_sf_changed=1&d%5Bpf_Species%5D&d%5Bpf_Interest%5D&d%5BSpecies%5D&d%5BActivity%5D&d%5BCount%5D&d%5BObserver%5D=Tereza+Sou%C4%8Dkov%C3%A1&d%5Bmunicipality%5D&d%5BSiteName%5D=Na+Ber%C3%A1nku&d%5BDateType%5D=2&d%5BDateExact%5D&d%5BDateFrom%5D&d%5BDateTo%5D&d%5BSeasonFrom%5D&d%5BSeasonTo%5D&d%5BYearFrom%5D&d%5BYearTo%5D&fbclid=IwAR2dd9Z_uCYfemRfcsL5RZZRS475Vy1CN_ZUIYqM7e8lYhbjmdQ4hMeUtDE#sf=1&dm=0&url_fmt_ver=0.2&iDisplayLength=100&pager_PaginationType=full_numbers&gal_width=3&iDisplayStart=0&iSortCol_0=0&iSortDir_0=desc&current_sf_changed=1&d%5Bpf_Species%5D=&d%5Bpf_Interest%5D=&d%5BSpecies%5D=&d%5BActivity%5D=&d%5BCount%5D=&d%5BObserver%5D=Tereza+Sou%C4%8Dkov%C3%A1&d%5Bmunicipality%5D=&d%5BSiteName%5D=Na+Ber%C3%A1nku&d%5BDateType%5D=2&d%5BDateExact%5D=&d%5BDateFrom%5D=&d%5BDateTo%5D=&d%5BSeasonFrom%5D=&d%5BSeasonTo%5D=&d%5BYearFrom%5D=&d%5BYearTo%5D=

Comment: Looks like a Chrome-specific problem, Edge only opens one tab (I tried both).

Comment: In my case, I could reproduce the issue in both Chrome and Edge. I got two request ids which are different from the original one. It seems that word sends two related requests to browser when Word handles the operation on the original url.